# Serial Port Terminal transmitting at 300 baudrate

Tags: serial, communication, rs232, terminal

I have been using Hercules SerialPort Terminal for a while now and its pretty cool. But now, I need to send data's at 300Baud, but Hercules stops at 9600baud.

I find TeraTerm which looks okay as well, but I need help on how I can send data's in Hexadecimal, just like I can do in Hercules, as it appears I can only send ascii characters alone. Is anyone familiar with TeraTerm? Do recommend other serial port terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I just noticed your "Do recommend other serial port terminal.", so to answer your question:

> Hexadecimal, just like I can do in Hercules, as it appears I can only send ascii characters alone. Is anyone familiar with TeraTerm?

No.

---

Just use [H-Term](http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/). Its free and supports "all" baud
rates and input/output format can be ASCII, hex, binary and decimal.

[image: H-Term 1]
[image: H-Term 2]